# how to migrate order , customer data mysql from one environment to another

Tags: magento2, database, importexport, data-migration

need table detail which we need export order , customer attribute from same version of magneto but different server

- need table name .
- any admin import /export method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the customers & customer addresses you should be able to use the [export](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-export.html) & [import](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-import.html) functionalities OOTB Magento.

However, for the orders it's a bit trickier as the data is scattered across multiple tables and a direct tables import might not work as entity keys need to be matched. So probably, another option is to use a custom 3rd party module from the magento marketplace.